# How to extract Call Graph(Collaboration diagram) details from xml?

Tags: doxygen

I used doxygen on my java source code to generate call graphs and collaboration diagrams.
My goal is to get data shown in collaboration diagrams to xml format.
What I need is the data flow in my source code i.e. interactions between one class to another and one function to another(same/different class).
Basically the data shown in Collaboration diagram.
Is there any way that doxygen can help me get this info?

I tried to go through output html files generated from doxygen but can't find anything.
If I get xml out files from doxygen can I get the above described information?

Comment: Did you try to generate the XML output? Did you have a look at the setting: `REFERENCES_RELATION`? Which version of doxygen are you using?